# Basel Problem Sum bigger than the integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Recently I was playing around with the Basel problem I've noticed a weird result?
 I know I've made some kind of mistake but when calculating the integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ from 1 to infinity,the result is 1. And it is well known that the sums equate to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ which is bigger than 1.

Any explanation why this should make sense ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The integral is not equal to the sum

Comment: This is fairly obvious if you compare the left Riemann sums of the same integral to itself.

Comment: They shouldn't be equal but the integral should be bigger ? i think i'm missing some vital obvious reason

Answer (score 2):

For the  Riemann's sum  to converge to the integral you need your $\Delta x$ to approach to zero.

For your partition you have  $\Delta x=1$, which does not approach zero.

For a given $n,$ we have $$1/4+1/9+...+\frac {1}{n^2} <\int _1^n \frac {1}{x^2} dx < 1+1/4+...+\frac {1}{(n-1)^2}$$

So there is no problem if we get $$\frac {\pi^2}{6} -1 <1< \frac {\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think a picture would help here.  Feel free to edit and replace with a better picture.  The integral is the area under the red curve from $1$ to $\infty$.  The Basel sum is the area under the rectangles with the blue tops.  It should be clear that the integral is less than the sum, since $\dfrac1{x^2}$ is strictly decreasing for $x>0$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it make sense now, but if we expanded the integral as a sums.it will contain the infinite series plus other corrections that are positive  that's my reasoning . the problem is i cannot locate the flaw

Comment: we'd have to see your work to address that problem